# How to display/see the default values in Admin for translated fields using Django's modeltranslation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to translate some models in an existing project, and I'm learning how to do that using the [modeltranslate](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html) extension. To experiment, I've added Spanish as an additional language to English and set English as a default in the `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'modeltranslation',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'debug_toolbar'
    ...
]

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
)
MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_PREPOPULATE_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_AUTO_POPULATE = True
```

The model:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`admin.py`:

```
class EquipmentAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    ordering = ('name',)
```

`translation.py`:

```
@register(Equipment)
class EquipmentTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
```

When trying to edit an Equipment object now in the dashboard, I see two empty text fields with the following names:

[image]

But the original name field and its value are not shown. Even in the model's table now there are no names displayed at all as can be seen here:

[image]

Questions:

1. How can I see the original value of these translated fields?
2. How do I keep seeing Equipment names in the overall model's view (the second screenshot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Django Modeltranslate" creates new database fields, in your case `name_en` and  `name_es` without removing the original `name` field.

You'will need to copy the contents of the old  `name` field to the generated ones, and I think that the easy way is to write a custom migration. You can create a file in the migrations folder of your app, with content similar to, and run the migrations command:

```py
def _copy_initial_names(apps, schema_editor):
    from your_app.models import Equipment
    for e in Equipment.objects.all():
        e.name_es = e.name
        e.name_en = e.name
        e.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('your-app', '00xx_migration_when_modeltranslation_installs'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(_copy_initial_names)
    ]
```

You can do it runing an sql query against your database or otherwise, but with a migration you don't need to remember to do it in another enviroment or in the future.

Comment: I was hoping to find an automatic/cleaner way to keep seeing the original values in admin as this custom migration would be quite messy and hard to scale to more fields and languages. Thank you!

Comment: @Mota, you can simply run `python manage.py update_translation_fields`, but I think that the migration is best option if you work in the project with other people.

Comment: Oh that's brilliant! Luckily I work on a project solo. Thanks a lot for these tips!